# Set DataTemplate control property binding to the item from an ItemsSource collection?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, itemtemplate, itemssource

I have an ItemsCountrol with its ItemsSource property bound to an ObservableCollection. I have a usercontrol (TeamUserControl) that displays this type. I created a datatemplate that loads this usercontrol for each customtype item in the itemssource collection. At this point any Binding statements I make inside TeamUserControl can reference Team properties directly by path {Binding Path=TeamOwner} and work. Is there a way to bind a reference to the ItemsSource item the usercontrol is representing? For example, in the TeamUserControl creating a dependancy property of type Team and have it bound to the instance of the item from the ItemsSource.

```
    <ItemsControl Name="ItemCtrl" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=League.Teams}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <mycontrols:TeamUserControl AttachedTeam="{Binding ???}" TeamOwnerName="{Binding Path=TeamOwner}"/>
        </DataTemplate> 
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

In this example the window is representing a class "League" which has the property:
ObservableCollection Teams. And there is a class "Team" which has the property:TeamOwner. The TeamUserControl has two dependancy properties: AttachedTeam of type Team, and TeamOwnerName of type string.

I included the team-owner property reference to show that there is an instance of Team for each of these usercontrols. I am just not sure how to reference it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand you, you should to write

```
<mycontrols:TeamUserControl AttachedTeam="{Binding}" TeamOwnerName="{Binding Path=TeamOwner}"/>
```

`{Binding}` statement will bind to current item in ItemsSource, where type `T` is type which  your `ObservableCollection<T> League.Teams` uses.

I also recommend you to read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) article about ItemsControl, and look around `Binding` to make it clear for yourself, what you can bind to.

Comment: This is how I thought it should be working. However, I get binding errors where it is trying to convert between a source type of TeamUserControl and target type Team. That error has me completely confused since the ItemsSource is an OC<Team>. Stepping back, if I do not define an ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate I just get a class name "Team". I am trying to tell it for each class Team object, use this TeamUserControl usercontrol.

Comment: Yeah, you were right. Turns out, in my TeamUserControl I had (for debugging) set the DataContext to (DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}") which was keeping all of my Window binding statements for working as expected. I removed that and everything is good. Thanks.